# CloudKit - Public and Private database - messaging platform

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I'm trying to Google this for last 2 hours and found practically nothing useful.
Let's say I want to create a messaging application with contacts on CloudKit platform.

You use a public database for Users. Let's say you can search people on the platform via e-mail address. So the e-mail is a public information stored in Users record type. However this user also has secret information that only accepted contacts can see. You invite him to be your contact which saves into Public database and sends a notification of some sort.

What now? How do you share a secret information about User, such as phone number, or, let's say, all of his contacts. `CKShare` doesn't seem to solve this kind of problem. Also, if I message the other person privately, where does this record get saved? Into a public database? Eh.

Sure I can save it all in a public database but how is that secure? Can't somebody then get the data if the app can?
I read about encrypting the data but that sounds to me like a lot of work and confusion and don't even know how could you share the keys on demand.

Comment: The public database is exactly that; a database that is accessible to everyone. The private database is actually a file in the users's own iCloud store (it isn't visible in their iCloud Drive, however). `CKShare` allows a user to make a specific record in their private database visible to another user. It may well be that CloudKit is not the datatstore you are looking for

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my view, Apple really goofed up by calling it a "Public" database **because it's not actually public**.

Your CloudKit data in the Public database can only be accessed in a few ways:

- **Authorized Users:** App Store Connect users can be granted access to make calls to your container via Apple's CloudKit APIs. Usually this is only your Apple ID and maybe that of a colleague.
- **Web Servers:** you can make calls to the Public DB if you have a server-to-server key installed.
- **Web Pages:** JavaScript code can make calls to the DB from *certain domains* specified by you in the CloudKit Dashboard.

So don't think of it as making it available to anyone anywhere. That would be a ridiculous architecture for Apple to implement as the default. Apple's Public database just means it **can** be accessed **through authorized channels** to any user that installs your app.

With that out of the way, you can store all that information you describe in your Public database. For a messaging app, people are going to need to look up other people and potentially communicate with anyone in the system. So all the data has to be in the same place.

`CKShare` wasn't really designed to support shared data like this. It's more for sharing a specific document with a set of people. Records shared via `CKShare` should be viewed as shared temporarily. If a user deletes your app or removes the share, all the participants immediately lose access. If you want data to live on (like in a chat room) then you need to make it user-independent by storing it in the Public database and granting users access to it.

I recommend creating your own `User` `recordType` since Apple's default `Users` `recordType` can't be queried (except by ID/`recordName`). So if you added an `email` field on to the `Users` `recordType`, you wouldn't be able to look up users by email. Instead, create your own `User` type and you'll be able to search by `email` all you want.

I'd move forward with your Public database implementation. You will have to manage sharing and subscribing to records manually, but it's the same amount of work as using `CKShare` (but a lot more flexible).

Comment: Great, thanks. Anyway, if you are an authorised person (so anybody having iCloud and is registered on the platform using the app), can’t you just reverse engineer the API and authorise yourself with the same credentials as you would do using the app? I know it’s apple right? I just don’t get it. Cracks for games, hacks and clones or apis, for example api for snapchat are reverse engineered and pinging their api in the way they want like the app would do.

Comment: Clifton, I see you were on StackOverflow yesterday but I am still looking for an answer on this.

Comment: @Martin. If you click on your container within the CloudKit Dashboard, there's a button in the upper-right called **Container Permissions...** and that shows which Apple IDs have access to your container. Screenshot: https://d.pr/i/rEBoYn I'm pretty sure the Apple ID has to be listed there in order to make Swift API calls from the app in Xcode. You can contact Apple support to confirm, though.

Comment: Apple uses CloudKit for a number of their key services like Photos, Notes, etc. so if reverse-engineering were a frequent problem then we'd hear about it. You have to be able to crack an Apple ID to get access to things, and that's rare.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. You store the public information in the public database.

And your secret private information is in your private database. When you make a contact that you want to share more data with, you can use a CKShare linked to an individual to share your secret private information.

It is a little confusing cause your imagining your contact list and secret information is held in a database on your device, only it isn't. It is all held remotely as permissions to see secret private data held in other people's private databases.

In the meantime, you need to save the links to the shared private information your friends have agreed to share with you in your private database. Late last year, I build an app that uses this sort of scheme. Within it you can take a photo, it is stored in your private database, you send a link to the ckshare of said photo to a list of users, who are then able to access it. The photo in case is the secret private information.